# dividing function to a separate file

Tags: reactjs, three.js, dat.gui

I'm building a application with Three.js that allows the user to adjust the input. I would like to move the **userGUI** function into a separate file, but it has to be called in the **startAnimationLoop** function for the animation to be rendered.

**Dat.Gui** (i would like this part to be in a separate file)

```
   userGUI = () => {
   this.gui = new dat.GUI();
   var controls = function() {
   this.RotationSpeed = 0.005;
}
  this.title = new controls();
  this.gui.add(this.title, 'RotationSpeed', 0.005, 0.1);
  }
```

**requestAnimationFrame()**

```
  startAnimationLoop = () => {
    const tableBoard = this.scene.getObjectByName('tableSurface');
    tableBoard.rotation.y += this.title.RotationSpeed; //This is where i use the value from the GUI
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.startAnimationLoop);
  };
```

Any suggestions on how i can move the **userGUI** part into a separate file and stil call it like i'm doing on the 3'rd row in the **startAnimationLoop** function?

Comment: What is your application environment? Are you using es6 modules, or script tags? Are you building in a framework like Vue?

Answer (score 1):

gui.js

```
userGUI = () => {
...
}

export const gui = new userGUI()
```

main.js

```
import { gui } from 'gui.js'

startAnimationLoop = () => {
...
    tableBoard.rotation.y += gui.title.RotationSpeed;
...
};
```